# Запуск REST сервисов (желательно под NET.CORE) без IIS

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, rest, iis

Уважаемые господа,

сейчас я пытаюсь улучшить проект, написанный в клиент-серверной архитектуре. клиент - браузерное приложение, довольно грамотно сделанное, в оснвном - jQuery, слегка приправленное ангуляром.

С сервером повезло меньше. Это один ("монолитный") сайт, написанный на ASP.NET (к счастью, C#). Заметная часть кода - больше 80 процентов - это REST-сервер, точнее, большой набор функций, которые работают в контексте HTTP, подразумевают, что им сделали POST пааметров и в результате своей работы выплёвывают JSON.

Все остальное, кроме этих функций, довольно бессодержательно, я собираюсь перенести это на NGINX как статические файлы и в некоторых редких случаях переделать с серверных на клиентские templates.

А в REST функциях есть много нетривиальной логики и работы с базой данных.
Чтобы это всё переделывать и развивать я хочу сделать, чтобы отдельные функции можно было запускать под NET.CORE, и как следует обложить тестами - потому, что тестировать REST - это милейшее дело и под это емть большой инструментарий.

А теперь внимание - вопрос.

Не посоветуете ли вы мне какой то инструмент - "запускалку" REST - методов? Чтобы ей, грубо говоря, можно было сказать, что такой то комбинации URL и метода (GET, POST и т.п) соответствует такой то метод в таком то C# классе? И чтобы при этом был HTTP-контекст, совместимый с тем, что предоставляет IIS. Ну, то есть, эдакий мини-веб-сервер, который предназначен специально для запуска REST-функций?

Спасибо заранее за советы!

Comment: Непонятно, что именно вы хотите, но ответ вероятно будет скорее Swagger чем Postman

Comment: Специально для rest запускалки я не знаю, но есть же  легковесные северы, экспресс например или [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows)

Comment: В net core есть встроенный простой web-сервер - kestrel. Включается тривиально `.UseKestrel()` (остальное легко гуглится), дальше просто запускаете ваше приложение, как если бы это было простое консольное приложение и используете Postman для написания и выполнения тестов для REST. Ну это если я правильно понял ваше желание...

Comment: @rdorn собственно, на него я и дал ссылку выше :)

Comment: @tym32167 это я уже после того как написал заметил =)

Comment: Господа, огромное спасибо за советы! только что добрался до компа, уже гуглю. Из моих собственных находок - собираюсь посмотреть проектик https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine

Comment: @rdorn на самом деле он "включается" ещё тривиальнее: можно просто ничего не писать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov можно, но не очевидно и лично я не очень люблю магию умолчаний, хотя в ряде случаев такой вариант имеет свои преимущества.